# Access Optional property in multiple function for calculations - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, null-coalescing

I have a NSObject Subclass. Say  CityWalks

class CityWalks{
    var totalCount:Int?
}

How do I use this property further? Should I check the nil coalescing every time this value is accessed.

example:

let aObject =

say in one fucntion (function1()) , I need to access this value, then it would like `(aObject!.totalCount ?? 0)`

```
func function1(){
 ...Some Access code for the object....
 (aObject!.totalCount ?? 0)
}
```

Similarly in every other function(function2())  , I will have to write the same code.

```
func function2(){
 ...Some Access code for the object....
 (aObject!.totalCount ?? 0)
}
```

So, what could be a better approach for such field, considering this property might receive a value from server or might not.

Comment: Why did you define the property as an optional?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default value for this property just assign this value as default value.

```
class YourClass {
   var totalCount  = 0
}
```

I'd recommend you avoid using an optional value if it's possible. Because optional values its a first place when you can get an error.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments and the other answer using an optional is not really optimal in your case. It seems like you might as well use a default value of 0.

However, to clarify, you have to check the value when unwrapping the optional.
Sometimes it's possible to pass an optional to UIElement etc and then you don't really need to do anything with them

There are pretty ways of checking for nil in optional values built into swift so you can build pretty neat code even though you work with optional.

Look in to `guard let` and `if let` if you want to know more about unwrapping values safely.

if let

```
if let totalWalks = aObject?.totalCount {
    //operate on totalWalks
}
```

guard

```
guard let totalWalks = aObject?.totalCount else { return }
//operate on totalWalks
```

There are also cases where you will want to call a function on an optional value and in this case you can do so with `?`

```
aObject?.doSomething()
```

Any return values this function might have will now be wrapped in an optional and you might have to unwrap them as well with an `if let` or `guard`

When working with optionals you should try to avoid forcing the unwrap with `!` as even though you at the moment know that the value is not null that might after a change in the code not be true anymore.